# How to use structure map to inject database context in thread safe way?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, thread-safety, structuremap

Database context is not thread-safe so I need to find a way to use it inside the parallel for each block. Yes. I could create DB context inside the parallel for each operation, but I would like to avoid creating database context inside my method as this would make unit tests harder to create. How can i achieve this?  For example: Can I register dependency so that it creates new database connection every time item is queried from database.
Something like this:

```
For<MyDbContext>().Use(() => new MyDbContext());
```

Register dependency using structure map:

```
For<MyDbContext>().Use(() => new MyDbContext()); 
Scan(scanner => { scanner.WithDefaultConventions(); scanner.AssemblyContainingType<ICodeThing>(); });
```

I hope `Use(() => new MyDbContext())` would create new database connection every time database is queried thus eliminating thread safety related problems when used similar to this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(params, new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, param=> { var data= _database.table.Where(q =>q.field == param.fieldvalue).toList();

/*Fetch data from third party API and do some processing related to param -item. Relatively slow operation so would like to do multiple operations in parallel.*/

 _database.SaveChanges(); });
```

Comment: Based on the usage `_database` is already resolved instance of context, so no matter how you will register it it still will be a single instance which should not be used from different threads at the same time.

Comment: _"Can I register dependency so that it creates new database connection every time item is queried from database."_ - no, because querying is handled by the context itself not by the DI container.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [factory support via `Func`](http://structuremap.github.io/the-container/lazy-resolution/#funct) which seems to be available out of the box with `StructureMap` in combination with `Transient` (see [supported lifecycles doc](http://structuremap.github.io/object-lifecycle/supported-lifecycles/)) registration (note that this potentially can be troublesome in some context usage scenarios):

```cs
x.For<MyDbContext>().Use<MyDbContext>().Transient();
```

And then in the service you can resolve factory:

```
Func<MyDbContext> _databaseFactory...

Parallel.ForEach(params, 
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 }, 
    p => 
    { 
        var db = _databaseFactory()
        var data = db.table ....
        // ....
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Another approach is to use the provided by framework [DbContext factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor).